# How to set query parameters with same name as Guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

I have no problem setting query parameters in Guzzle. But I can't add parameters with the same name. My query params array is below.

```
$query_params = array(
                'test' => 'abc',
                'test2' => true,
                'limit' => 10,
                'item_id' => '8159'
            );
```

I want the query parameters to be as follows.

```
?test=abc&test2=true&limit=10&item_id=8159&item_id=333&item_id=435&item_id=123..
```

I want to duplicate the item_id parameter as above. And I tested as follows, but this time a bad request was returned from the service. When I looked at the link, I saw that the '=' symbols turned into strange strings like 5BD0%. There was no problem in other parameters. But that's what happened to those with the same name.

```
...'item_id' => array('123','3243','243')...
```

The guzzle setting is as follows:

```
 $response = $this->client->request('GET', $endpoint, array(
                    'headers' => array(
                        'X-API-KEY' => KEY
                    ),
                    'query' => $query_params
                ));
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved above mentioned problem using Guzzle [query request params](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#query).

I changed the query params as below. Then I changed the value of the guzzle 'query'.

```php
$query_params = [
            'test' => 'abc',
            'test2' => true,
            'limit' => 10,
            'item_id' => array('8159','123')
    ];
$response = $this->client->request('GET', $endpoint, [
                   'headers' => [
                        'X-API-KEY' => KEY
                   ],
                   'query' => Query::build($query_params)
            ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

All is there : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.http-build-query.php (the function `http_build_query()` is what you need).

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I want Guzzle to do it.